# Python by-object confusion

Tags: python, immutability

**Duplicate edit :** There is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference) that has been marked as similar, but it is different because it talks only about .append and full list instanciation. My issue is about offset assignement (data[j]) and iterators (used in the first function).

---

I'm being a little confused with Python by-object information passing. From my text book, when the function receive it's parameters, it creates an alias to the initial object. Also, about mutable param : "we note that reassigning a new value to a formal parameter, such as by setting list = [ ], does not alter the actual parameter; such reassignment breaks the alias".

Now I have these 2 functions :

```
def mult(data, factor):
    for val in data:
        val *= factor
data = [i for i in range(5)]
mult(data, 3)
print(data)

def mult2(data, factor):
    for j in range(len(data)):
        data[j] *= factor
data = [i for i in range(5)]
mult2(data, 3)
print(data)
```

This yields the output 0,1,2,3,4 and 0,3,6,9,12 respectively.

In mult2, we change the value of data by reassigning a new value. Why isn't the alias broken?

Additionnaly, in the first function, if I loop through every value of the list and I change it, is the alias broken?

Comment: Try returning your values from the functions: `return val` Then store the result of the function as a variable and print that: `data = scale1(data, 3); print(data)`

Comment: I know that val is just an int my problem is with data. Why isn't val changing the value of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for val in data:
        val *= factor`

You are reassigning val and so its "link" to data is broken

`for j in range(len(data)):
        data[j] *= factor`

You are using an "offset" from data, so the "link" doesn't get broken

Comment: I get that, but why? I don't understand why using an offset doesn't break the link but simply looping through an iterator does?

Comment: this would make more sense if you knew c. let me try to explain:
in the first approach, you are saying val is pointing at a value in a list, then you assign val a different value, you didn't change anything in the list you just tell cal to point at something else, so the list remains unchanged.

in the second approach data is a list, think of data as something point at the beginning of a set of cells so `data[0] ` would give you the first cell in data, if you change it you change teh cell directly, not something pointing at it. does this make more sense?

Comment: It's getting much clearer! Does this mean any action on data inside the function (append, remove, pop) will change the value outside of the function too?

Comment: yes, now you are getting it!